# Trying to identify an IC; don't recognize the logo. Top markings 4307 and RR623

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

The only markings on this chip (other than the logo, which I don't recognize) are: 4307 and RR623.  This chip is on an audio circuit board, in the sub-woofer of a TV sound system.

I did a search in Google and searched the numbers in DigiKey site.  No luck identifying it.

Second image posted.  Speaker lugs to left of Q1; 470uF electrolytic to the right.  Larger IC below is a linear amplifier.

[image: Closeup of IC]

[image: Larger view for context]

[image: Schematic of MOSFET package]

Comment: it always help to show more than just the IC itself, but also the circuitry surrounding it, and if possible (in your case, it seems to be) to at least partially try to draw a schematic.

Comment: It looks to me as pins 1 to 3 are shorted and also pins 5 to 8. That probably makes this a MOSFET instead of an IC. Also note the label: **Q1** which also indicates it is a transistor, not an IC.

Comment: Was about to say the same stuff Bimpelrekkie said; this looks to be a transistor in an SO-8 package.

Comment: thanks for the replies.. is there a way to attach a larger pic of the PWB in a comment?

Comment: Try the "edit" button under the question.

Comment: Thanks, @Hearth.  See updated post.

Comment: Now google "4307 mosfet" and, at least for me, the 2nd hit is for a device from a company with a logo like the one on your part.

Comment: Manufacturer is **sinopower**, and this does appear to be a MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who pitched in to ID this chip.  Can someone please tell me how to mark this as 'answered'?

Comment: Noone answered, everyone just added comments. Ask @ThePhoton to write an answer, so you can credit him for the google hint (by accepting the answer). Or answer it yourself.

Comment: Feel free to answer yourself. I think then you have to wait 24 hours to accept your own answer